# Symfony2 validation group for array

Tags: php, arrays, validation, symfony

I want to validate an array using validation group because of some conditions but validation group doesn't seem affect array?

```
$params = [
    'type' => 'a',
    'province' => 'b',
    'district' => 'c'
];

$constraints = new Collection([
    'type' => [new NotBlank()],

    'province' => [new NotBlank(['groups' => ['selection']])],
    'district' => [new NotBlank(['groups' => ['selection']])],

    'distance' => [new NotBlank(['groups' => ['location']])],
    'lat' => [new NotBlank(['groups' => ['location']])],
    'lon' => [new NotBlank(['groups' => ['location']])],
]);

$errors = $this->container->get('validator')->validate($params, $constraints, ['selection']);
```

Validation errors:

```
Array[distance]:
This field is missing. (code 1)
Array[lat]:
This field is missing. (code 1)
Array[lon]:
This field is missing. (code 1)
```

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `'allowMissingFields' => true,` like this :

```
$constraints = new Collection(
'allowMissingFields' => true,
'fields' => [
    'type' => [new NotBlank()],

    'province' => [new NotBlank(['groups' => ['selection']])],
    'district' => [new NotBlank(['groups' => ['selection']])],

    'distance' => [new NotBlank(['groups' => ['location']])],
    'lat' => [new NotBlank(['groups' => ['location']])],
    'lon' => [new NotBlank(['groups' => ['location']])],
]);
```

https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/constraints/Collection.html

The CollectionValidator is checking if the field exists before the constraint NotBlank is validated.